# How set a Panel on right side of another Panel?

Tags: delphi, panel, toolbar, vcl, delphi-10.4-sydney

I want set a "`Panel2`" on right side of a"`Panel3`" of mode that when "`Panel2`" hide "`Panel3`", the "`Panel2`" still can be visible to show "`Panel3`" again. All that i have until now is:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel2.Parent := Self;
  Panel2.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom];
  Panel2.Caption := '>>>';
  Panel2.ParentBackground := False;
  Panel2.SetBounds(0, Panel1.Height, 30, 20);

  Panel3.Parent := Self;
  Panel3.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom];
  Panel3.Caption := '';
  Panel3.Color := $0000F9FF;
  Panel3.ParentBackground := False;
  Panel3.Visible := False;
  Panel3.SetBounds(0, Panel1.Height + Panel2.Height, 100, ClientHeight);
end;

procedure TForm1.Panel2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Panel2.Caption = '>>>' then
  begin
    AnimateWindow(Panel3.Handle, 150, AW_ACTIVATE or AW_SLIDE or AW_HOR_POSITIVE);
    Panel2.Caption := '<<<';
  end
  else if Panel2.Caption = '<<<' then
  begin
    AnimateWindow(Panel3.Handle, 150, AW_HIDE or AW_SLIDE or AW_HOR_NEGATIVE);
    Panel2.Caption := '>>>';
  end;
end;
```

[image]

"**>>>**" is the "`Panel2`" and yellow is "`Panel3`".

I'm expecting a effect like the "arrow button" of Team Viewer that hide and show the toolbar

[image]

Comment: `Panel2.Left := Panel3.Width` ?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Yes! Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you're reinventing a `TCategoryPanelGroup`?